# Add .Net Resource to separate java script file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, resources

How I can add .Net resource to separate java script file, I can add resource to javascript by add script to View and set value @Resource.Layout.Name

like this code in View

```
<script>
alert(@Resource.Layout.Msg)
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include how you are including this script to your view. Thanks!

Comment: No , I mean I want use functions of script , like function login() ,  the result of login will display message for end user  from .Net Resource because  we support multi language.

Comment: Hi Jon, will you open another question and comment here, someone closed it without understanding the full context.

Comment: Hi Jerdine, I created new question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61318084/use-net-resource-in-function-with-separate-java-script-file